# Java - how to calculate and compare binary tree

Tags: java, recursion

some homework question:
i need to check if binary tree is following this rule:
in every node there is number, i need to check if this number is bigger or equal to all the nodes under it.

if all the tree is following that rule the method should return true.
i wrote this code:

```
public static boolean isSigma(Node n)
{
    if (n == null)
        return true;
    if (n.getLeftSon() == null && n.getRightSon() == null)
        return true;
    else return n.getNumber() >= sumCalc(n) && isSigma(n.getLeftSon()) && isSigma(n.getRightSon());
}

private static int sumCalc(Node n) // return the sum of specific Node plus other Node/s that are under it
{
    if (n==null)
        return 0;
    else return n.getNumber() + sumCalc(n.getLeftSon()) + sumCalc(n.getRightSon());
}
```

**The left tree will return false, and the right tree will return true.**
[image]

**but for some reason the code is not working.
i checked for few trees and it giving me always false.**
BTW i have to write this in recursion methode and not allowed to change the public method signature.

Comment: I would step through you code in a debugger with the simplest example which causes a problem.  This will show you where your bug is. (That's what the tool is for)

Answer (score 2):

Rephrasing the question:
`isSigma(Node n)` should return true if the Number of Node n is bigger or equal to the sum of the Numbers of all its children and all its children are sigma too.

If this is what you're looking for, here is your solution:

```
public static boolean isSigma(Node n)  
{
    if (n == null) {
        return true;
    } else if (n.getLeftSon() == null && n.getRightSon() == null) {
        return true;
    } else if (n.getLeftSon() != null || n.getRightSon() != null) {
        boolean leftIsSigma = isSigma(n.getLeftSon());
        boolean rightIsSigma = isSigma(n.getRightSon());
        int sumOfChildren = sumCalc(n.getLeftSon()) + sumCalc(n.getRightSon());

        return ((n.getNumber() >= sumOfChildren) && leftIsSigma && rightIsSigma);
    }
}

private static int sumCalc(Node n) {
    if (n == null)
        return 0;
    return n.getNumber() + sumCalc(n.getLeftSon()) + sumCalc(n.getRightSon());
}
```

Comment: what you wrote is good, but i need also to check if all the children numbers are also bigger then their children. if all nodes have bigger values then all their children than the method return true.

Comment: still not sure if I understand you questions correctly, but I changed my solution to what I understand

Comment: @YuvalLevy may I kindly ask you to accept my answer? If it's not acceptable to you please let me know what I can do to make my answer better. I'd really appreciate the reputation I'd gain, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be better? :)

```
private static int sumCalc(Node n) {
    if (n == null)
        return 0;
    return n.getNumber() + sumCalc(n.getLeftSon()) + sumCalc(n.getRightSon());
}
```

Now you just use it like `sumCalc(rootNode);`

You should revise the idea of recursion.

...edit

Check out this line:

```
return n.getNumber() >= sumCalc(n) && isSigma(n.getLeftSon()) && isSigma(n.getRightSon());
```

keep in mind that sumCalc(n) counts all values of tree including this from n node. What you really want to check here is not `n.getNumber() >= sumCalc(n)`, but `n.getNumber() >= sumCalc(n) - n.getNumber()` which is equal to `n.getNumber() << 1 >= sumCalc(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is created by a clause in else case of isSigma():

```
   [A]  n.getNumber() >= sumCalc(n)
```

The definition of sumCalc() adds the weight/value of node n and all its children and their children and so on. Dry run the code. sumCalc(n) will return n.getNumber() + sumCalc() of children. So the statement [A] will always be false. (unless you are dealing with negative values)

Modify the method sumCalc() as follows:

```
  private static int sumCalc(Node n) 
  // return the sum of specific Node plus other Node/s that are under it
  {
    if (n==null)
       return 0;
    else 
       int childSum = n.getLeftSon().getNumber() + n.getRightSon().getNumber();
       return (childSum + sumCalc(n.getLeftSon()) + sumCalc(n.getRightSon()));
  }
```

Comment: "the quoted line will be eventually checking if the value of n is -ve or +ve" didnt understand what you meen by this line?